# Is it possible to connect to a nanomsg socket from a C# client?

Tags: c#, sockets, nanomsg

I am experimenting with nanomsg.

Is it possible to connect to a nanomsg socket from a  client using [.NET's Socket class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) or for that matter, any other socket library other than another nanomsg client?

Are there any online tutorials and/or examples about doing this?

For example, using nanocat, bind a socket to a port.  Then from C# .NET attempt to connect to the socket:

```
    Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Raw);
    s.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1234);
```

Comment: It seems as though there's already a [.NET library for nanomsg](https://github.com/mhowlett/NNanomsg). Looking at the documentation, it seems to me that it's a fairly elaborate protocol, including a distributed communications protocol. I would think you'd be much better off using the existing library instead of reimplementing all that.

Comment: I think your comment answers my question best.  If you revise  your answer to include this library reference, I'll mark your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sockets are sockets. They abstract network protocols, like TCP and UDP, and send bytes back and forth.

So yes, you can use `Socket` to connect to any other remote endpoint using TCP, even if that endpoint isn't even using sockets as their implementation.

Of course, you still have to be able to interpret the bytes. But that's not the job of the `Socket` class. It's only there to provide the connection and byte-based I/O.

If you are asking about dealing with the nanomsg protocol specifically, it seems as though there's already a [.NET library for nanomsg](https://github.com/mhowlett/NNanomsg). Looking at the documentation, it seems to me that it's a fairly elaborate protocol, including a distributed communications protocol. I would think you'd be much better off using the existing library instead of reimplementing all that.

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified. I can connect to the socket. Putty, for instance, can do it, but it closes immediately. In C#, I get exceptions depending on how I create the socket class. Basically, I can't get this to be useful yet.

Comment: I answered the question you asked, which is "is it possible to connect to nanomsg?" If you are having specific problems doing so, you need to post a good, complete, concise code example, describe what is happening, including the exact text of any error messages, and explain what you wanted to happen instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your clarification didn't really make this question any clearer.